# AWS CodeDeploy appspec.yml for Main and Sub branch setting?

Tags: github, yaml, aws-code-deploy

I have completed setting up my CodeDeploy in AWS, I setup a pipeline with 2 branches one for Main and one for Sub branch. The problem all changes goes to one Source Destination for the files. I temporarily fix this by changing the appspec.yml in the sub branch different from the main branch.

My Question is do appspec.yml has a configuration to setup 2 file source destination and identifying it for specific branch?

```
Main Branch
- /var/www/html/
Sub Branch
- /var/www/development/
```

[image]

Let me know if you already solve this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Create a common path on both servers. Let's assume var/www/app

This app folder should be symlink of your site root where the repo stands.

Server 1 ln -s path-to-sitefolder var/www/app

Server 2 ln - s path-to-secondsitefolder var/www/app

You will anyway create two pipelines for two branches, so it will not rewrite code on another branch

You just have to add destination as /var/www/app in appspec.yml